# Can I check what T-SQL statement had been executed in the database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a C# application, which will do thing in the database, but everything I am black boxed, is this possible I can check back what T-SQL statements had been run on SQL Server? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Profiler is definitely the way to go as serge said but I also like to keep this query in my pocket when I can't get approval to enable the profiler on production.

```
SELECT TOP 50 deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

Of course you will want to modify `TOP 50` to show more or less results.

Note: I've used this for such a long time I forgot that I didn't come up with it myself.  Originally I found it on [SQLAuthority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/03/sql-server-2005-last-ran-query-recently-ran-query/).  Credit where credit is due! :)

Comment: Also, I have used this on Sql Server 2005 and 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - use SQL Server Profiler:

[Using SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)